# Angular 5: Authentication guard automatically navigates to specified component

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-routing, angular-services

I have set an authentication guard with firebase email and password login, the issue is that it automatically triggers the route to the specified component.

I have implemented the authentication guard and set it in the correct module provider (because I have many providers in my application). This is my authentication service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Route ,CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild, CanLoad } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SimpleAuthService } from './simple-auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {
  constructor(private authService: SimpleAuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
    const url: string = route.path;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn(url);
  }
}
```

and this is the component class where I inject it (the login component):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SimpleAuthService } from '../../core/simple-auth.service';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login-cmp',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private toggleButton: any;
    private sidebarVisible: boolean;
    private nativeElement: Node;
    private email  ='user@dev.org'
    private password ='useruser';


    constructor(private element: ElementRef, public authService: SimpleAuthService,
        private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
            if (this.authService.login(this.email,this.password)) {
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            } else {
                this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
                this.sidebarVisible = false;
            }
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.login(this.email, this.password);
        var navbar : HTMLElement = this.element.nativeElement;
        this.toggleButton = navbar.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggle')[0];

        setTimeout(function() {
            // after 1000 ms we add the class animated to the login/register card
            $('.card').removeClass('card-hidden');
        }, 700);
    }
    sidebarToggle() {
        var toggleButton = this.toggleButton;
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-collapse')[0];
        if (this.sidebarVisible == false) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                toggleButton.classList.add('toggled');
            }, 500);
            body.classList.add('nav-open');
            this.sidebarVisible = true;
        } else {
            this.toggleButton.classList.remove('toggled');
            this.sidebarVisible = false;
            body.classList.remove('nav-open');
        }
    }

    login(username: string, password: string): void {
        this.authService.login(username, password).then(_ => {
          const redirectUrl: string = this.authService.redirectUrl || 'dashboard';
          this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
        });
      }
}
```

this my authentication service made using firebase:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Route ,CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild, CanLoad } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { User, UserCredential } from '@firebase/auth-types';
import { take, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleAuthService {
  user: Observable<User>;
  redirectUrl: string;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
  }

  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.user.pipe(take(1));
  }

  isLoggedIn(redirectUrl: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(authState => !!authState),
      tap(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);
  }

  logout(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']));
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea where I made a mistake?

Comment: Is `AuthService.login()` really a synchronous method? What is it actually returning? If it's something async such as an Observable<T> or Promise<T>, you wouldn't be able to check the results in an `if` statement. Are you tracking `AngularFireAuth.authState` as an observable in your `AuthService`?

Comment: I am going to add my authService

Comment: now it automatically navigate to the specified component even if I did not submit the username and the password

Comment: If you changed, your code, you will need to update your question with all parts to help understand what the issue is now. Keep in mind, you will not be able to use `if()` with async code, either observables or promises.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me this. I have updated the code

Comment: As I've described in my answer `if (this.authService.login(this.email,this.password)) {}`, will not work. That **always** returns true. At minimum in your `LoginComponent`, you need to `this.authService.login(this.email,this.password).then(result => this.router.navigate(['dashboard']))`

Answer (score 5):

The base issue is that your `login()` method is asynchronous, but you are attempting to check the result as if it was a synchronous method. In addition, `login()` isn't even returning anything currently `void`, so there wouldn't any result to check for. Either way, even if the result was returned as a `Promise<T>`, you'd need to use `then()` to access the results/success, and `catch()` to handle errors accordingly in the component. You simply will not be able to check the results in an `if()` statement like that. At a basic level, if you are attempting to check a function returning a `Promise<T>` in an if statement, it will always be truthy, regardless if `catch()` is triggered milliseconds later.

```
function login(): Promise<boolean> {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}

if(login()) {} // this is always true regardless of `catch()` is triggered sometime in the future
```

With angularfire2, you can track the authentication state  of the user in realtime as an `Observable<User>` that can be used in methods such as `canActivate()`. Here is an approach you could take that exposes the `Observable<User>` in the auth service, that can be used to check login status, get the current user, or even in a template to display something like user avatar image with the `async` pipe. There are RxJS operators such as `tap`, `take`, and `map` to help avoid unnecessarily keeping subscriptions active. With these methods mostly returning `Observable<T>`, you can additionally pipe additional operators/actions in your other services or components to take full advantage of RxJS.

Auth Service:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { User, UserCredential } from '@firebase/auth-types';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<User>;
  redirectUrl: string;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
  }

  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.user.pipe(take(1));
  }

  isLoggedIn(redirectUrl: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(authState => !!authState),
      tap(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  logout(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']));
  }
}
```

Auth Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
    const url: string = route.path;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn(url);
  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, public authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.login(this.email, this.password);
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.authService.login(username, password).then(_ => {
      const redirectUrl: string = this.authService.redirectUrl || '/some-default-route';
      this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
    });
  }
}
```

An overall recommendation, you will want to take better advantage services for communication between components. You are heavily using both DOM manipulation with JavaScript and jQuery, which defeats the purpose of Angular and will likely cause issues as elements will not be available when you expect due to component lifecycle and rendering. Using services and RxJS you can set CSS classes via directives [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). Check out the documentation on [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) for an example of how components can communicate at a basic level. It if it's Bootstrap you need, you should consider Angular based Bootstrap components/libraries that hook into the Angular component life cycle and do not depend on jQuery.

**Update:**

Based on the updated code you provided, you are still attempting to check success of async Promise `login()` using an `if` statement in your constructor. This will always cause the redirect as `login()` is returning a promise which would be truthy value. Instead try using `then()`/`catch()` on the returned promise in your `LoginComponent` to respond to success/error of Firebase's `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`:

```
this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
  .then(result => this.router.navigate(['dashboard']))
  .catch(err => {
    this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
    this.sidebarVisible = false;
  });
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: this didn't solve the issue it keeps navigating to the component

Comment: I'm trying to help, but you need to identify which piece of your code is causing the redirect specifically now, maybe even through console.log() statements. I've used this exact code successfully on multiple projects to prevent navigation to protected routes and redirect after login. Also, did you updated your constructor to remove that if statement? Try updating your answer by removing all the DOM manipulation stuff and just focus on the authentication and authentication guard flow.

Comment: For troubleshooting, I'd remove `login()` from the constructor, you are effectively calling `login()` twice, once in the constructor, then almost immediately in the `ngOnInit()` method.